# How to show Touches and Pointer Location on Screen without Developer Mode?

Tags: cyanogenmod, touchscreen, chromecast, oneplus-two

I am trying to use my phone as controller and my 42 TV as display. Chromecast is casting the thing.

- I have tried *Show Touches* and *Show pointer location* as described [here](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_developer_options/en) in Developer options. However, I do not want to keep Developer options active all the time. Also, some of the features fail too often, causing epileptic continuous blinking in different colours.
- I do not have any other option (etc `Show GPU view updates`) on in *Developer Options*.

Phone: Oneplus 2
OS: CyanogenMod 13

Comment: Have you tried the "Show Touches" option in the [Developer Options](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_developer_options/en)?

Comment: @benjamin Yes, I tried it. I do not however want to use Developer mode continuously. Either of the modes also fails too often, causing severe complications.

Comment: The blinking you are describing is most often caused by activating "Show GPU view updates" - which adds a red overlay to views rendered by the GPU. The developer options are the easiest option I guess. You don't have to enable "Show pointer Location" most likely. Maybe there is another way though which is better suited for you

Comment: @benjamin No, I do not have `Show GPU view updates` on. It happens just with those two settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No support for this in Android 6-7 by default without the developer mode.